# Opening Word File in GitLab instead of downloading

Tags: git, gitlab

I have uploaded docs along with code.

But In GitLab there is no option to open that document.

How can I achieve this in GitLab?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word is not a plain text file format, so there is no way to preview it online. And the even worse thing is git could not detect what content is changed if you changed one line in your Word document.

An option for you is transforming your Word to Markdown (*.md) file by tool or manually, GitLab as well GitHub support previewing this format by default, README.md is the most widely use case. There are some free online tools could achieve it, such as [this](https://word-to-markdown.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: Is there any other way to open word documents in GitLab?@Kevin Law

Comment: Can any one Tell me, How to download .md file from GitLab?@Kevin Law

Comment: Go to your repository, then click on the .md .md file, if everything goes right, you will see the rendered content of this .md file. A download button as well some other operation button will displayed above content. If what you clicked is word document, download button will also there without rendered content.